# How to create an Array or Dictionary whose values can only be String, Int and Boolean?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have a requirement where I need to create an array whose values can only be either String, Int or boolean.
Swift compiler should complain if I tried to add Double or any other value type.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
protocol Elem {} 
extension Int: Elem {}  
extension String: Elem {} 
extension Bool: Elem {} 
let arr = [Elem]()
```

Comment: Thanks.
Since you were first, I have to accept your answer

Comment: Referring to testing the code snippet, I did that and it works as it should, please accept my edit :)

Answer (score 9):

You can do it by declaring a dummy protocol

```
protocol SpecialType {}
```

and let conform the requested types to that protocol

```
extension String : SpecialType{}
extension Int : SpecialType{}
extension Bool : SpecialType{}
```

Now the compiler complains if you try to add a Double

```
let specialDict : [String:SpecialType] = ["1" : "Hello", "2": true, "3": 2.0]
// value of type 'Double' does not conform to expected dictionary value type 'SpecialType'
```

Comment: can we make extension of `[String:Any]` or `[[String:Any]]` with SpecialType??

Comment: This is not necessary. Just replace `Any` with `SpecialType`. The collections `Array` and `Dictionary` will consider it correctly.

Comment: no I mean what if I want to check that data is of type array or dictionary .. is this same thing we can use with array or dictionary?

Comment: I don't understand. The collection types are generics. The associated types are checked anyway.

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 , It's yes and no. Swift simply doesn't support that kind of extension for current version, but there's a proposal to support it. Once supported the syntax should be `extension Array: SpecialType where Element == String` (this should give  compiler error for now)

Comment: ok got it... thanks :)