# Can we mix types in an array in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

In Swift 3 playground, I want to create a mutable array with numbers at some indices and Strings at others. I get errors doing this:

```
var playerInfo = [[String]]()
playerInfo[0][2] = "Adam" //Error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
playerInfo[0][3] = "Martinez"
playerInfo[0][1] = "00"
```

EDIT:
Something like this?

```
var playerInfo: [[String:Any]] = [
     [
     "playerNumber" : "00",
     "playerFirstName" : "Adam",
     "playerLastName" : "Martinez"
     ]
]
```

Comment: You can create array of dictionary for this.

Comment: You cannot add items with index subscripting because all arrays are empty (no index 0).

Comment: I just answered another question like this: [How to create an Array or Dictionary whose values can only be String, Int and Boolean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43061928/how-to-create-an-array-or-dictionary-whose-values-can-only-be-string-int-and-bo/).

Comment: @NandiinBao The reason of the crash is not related to your linked answer.

Comment: As for the crash, @vadian is right. `var playerInfo = [[String]]()` only creates an empty array of empty arrays. `playerInfo[0]` would cause crash because there is no 0-th element in `playerInfo` since it's empty. Also even you construct the variable as `var playerInfo = [[String]](repeating: [], count: 100)`, calling `playerInfo[0][2]` would also cause crash. `playerInfo[0]` does exist this time, but it's an empty array, there is no 2-nd element in it.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the syntax correctly.

Try this:

```
var playerInfo = [[String]]()
playerInfo.append(["00","Adam","Martinez"])
```

**EDIT**

For your edit, you need a Dictionary:

```
var playerInfo = Dictionary<String, Any>()

playerInfo["playerNumber"] = "00"
playerInfo["playerFirstName"] = "Adam"
playerInfo["playerLastName"] = "Martinez"
```

Comment: When I implement your array method, I get an error in my project: Expected declaration.

Comment: Where exactly? I mean, in which line?